# Скрыть блок при нажатии вне его

Tags: jquery

Есть два input-а реализованные, как select. Если кликаем на первый блок, затем на второй, то первый должен закрываться
У них одинаковые классы.

```
$(this).on('click', function(e) {
        if (!$(e.target).closest(".container-input-select").find('.input-as-select').length) {
            $(this).find('.input-as-select-border-active').addClass('input-as-select-transform');
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Таких div - ов у меня несколько с одинаковыми классами.
И происходит сворачивание input, только если кликаем вне области, а при клике на второй input, поскольку у них одинаковые классы, первый не скрывается.

```
<div class="container-input-select">
    <div class="input-as-select">

        <input type="text" readonly>

        <div class="points-to-select-input uk-hidden">
            <ul class="uk-list">
                <li>+7-909-000-00-00</li>
                <li>+7-954-645-65-43</li>
                <li>Другое</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>     
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если  стоит задача сворачивать инпуты при клике ВНЕ их, то не проще ли добавить стили, которые свернут ВСЕ инпуты, кроме активного?

типа такого:

```css
.area {
  background-color: wheat;
  height: 200px;
  padding:1em;
}

.expanded {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  margin: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 1.25em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  vertical-align: top;
  transition-duration:0.5s;
}

.expanded:active,
.expanded:focus {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="area">
  Click outside textareas to collapse them<br>

  <textarea class="expanded">click me!</textarea>
  <textarea class="expanded">click me!</textarea>
  <textarea class="expanded">click me!</textarea>

</div>
```

Comment: А если не добавлять активный класс? Просто все в таком виде, как у кинул, есть такая возможность?

Comment: да там класс чисто для удобства. весь цимес в псевдоклассах `:active` и `:focus`, которые прописывать в HTML-код не надо (они означают определенное состояние элемента). Можно и без класса вообще: `textarea:active, textarea:focus { height:100px;}`. Высоту, кстати, можно задать и заранее неизвестную (типа `auto`), я задал в пикселах чтобы анимация работала.